# Eclipse RCP Application Headless Build

Tags: maven, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I have an RCP Application that I created in eclipse using the [Vogella Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html). Currently, I have to manually build the project using the export wizard.

I would like to create a headless build using Maven Tycho, and have attempted this using the [Vogella Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html).

I am running into the issue of not finding the `.mvn/extensions.xml` file and thus cannot execute a headless build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `.mvn/extensions.xml` does not exist. You have to create it yourself.

Just create a new directory `.mvn` and inside it a file `extensions.xml`. Then copy and paste the XML from chapter 2.3 of the Tycho tutorial.